# How to import an entire npm library into React Native, not just 1 file?

Tags: javascript, npm, react-native

I've been trying to import the sjcl library, which has many files, but I'm only able to import 1 file from it.

From command line:

```
npm install sjcl --save
react-native link
```

In a RN JS file:

```
import sjcl from 'sjcl';
```

Looks like this doesn't import everything in the sjcl node package, it only imports file sjcl.js from node_modules/sjcl/. I also need sha1.js from node_modules/sjcl/core/sha1.js. I've tried various ways of importing it, but nothing works.

**How can I import an entire npm library into a React Native project?**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem trying to load the ECC module, here is how I worked around it (I installed sjcl using npm).  Create a file LocalExports.js in which put this

```
import sjcl from 'sjcl';
export {default as sjcl} from 'sjcl';
window.sjcl = sjcl;
```

then import like this in any other file

```
import {sjcl} from './LocalExports';
import 'sjcl/core/bn'; 
import 'sjcl/core/ecc';
```

*edit - I just found this link, which is the official way to do this 
https://github.com/bitwiseshiftleft/sjcl/wiki/Getting-Started